# How to configure PMD violation threshold in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, static-analysis, pmd

I have created a jenkins job and below is the pom file. 
1. Can you please suggest a way to ignore a certain 'X' number of PMD violations?
2. Is this setup correct to generate PMD reports? Goal in Jenkins is  clean install pmd:check site

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                <!--<targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>-->

                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>


            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>

                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                <!--<targetJdk>1.6</targetJdk>-->
                <failurePriority>5</failurePriority>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <targetDirectory>./pmdOutput</targetDirectory>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/rulesets/basic.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jxr-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PMD Maven plugin doesn't allow to setup thresholds on number of violations, it either fails at the first violation of the given priority, or it doesn't.

What I would probably do is not run the `pmd:check` target, but have maven generate the reports, and use the [Jenkins' PMD plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PMD+Plugin) to parse the report xml and fail the build if needed.

The PMD plugin for Jenkins does allow more flexible threshold configuration.

Comment: I am using Jenkins' PMD plugin only goal as clean install pmd:check site. 
Where does Jenkin save the generated report? Can it not be saved at a common place?
How to make a build pass even inspite of PMD violation?

Comment: Hi @Johnco failOnViolation does not work either.. When only '<build>' is used the code builds regardless of the value of '<failOnViolation>' property. When only '<reporting>' is used the build fails regardless of 'failOnViolation' property.

Comment: `pmd:check` is the only goal to use the value of `<failOnViolation>` (defaults to true). It relies on `pmd:pmd` to generate the report, and then just fails the build or not. The task is bound to the `verify` lifecycle step, so it uses the `build` config, it should honor `<failOnViolation>` for `<build>`.

Comment: Jenkins' PMD plugin does not generate the report, but it parses a report generated during build and produces metrics / alters build result according to setup. You need to add a post-build step to publish PMD results, and make sure to setup where to look for pmd xml result (I think the default value works for Maven projects, but you should check it).

Comment: Thanks @Johnco My team is in the process of installing the required plugins. Shall keep you posted with the progress on this track.

Comment: Team is still in the process of installing plugins. I had one more query- Can the results of PMD be mailed? If yes how?

Answer (score 1):

Since version *3.10.0*, PMD has configuration option *maxAllowedViolations*:

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/cpd-check-mojo.html#maxAllowedViolations

```
 <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <maxAllowedViolations>180</maxAllowedViolations>
      </configuration>
</plugin>
```